# We have $3$ boxes, let people put $1$ ball in the box, what is the distribution of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Lets say we have $k$ boxes. We ask people to put each put $1$ ball in
>   the boxes. Assume we select people independently from one another. We
>   are interested in comparing the first two boxes.  We have three
>   categories, $X_1$ for box $1$, $X_2$ for box $2$ and $X_3$ for the others.
>
> $X_1 = 1$ if a randomly chosen person chose box $1$, its $0$ if they
>   chose a different box.
>
> $X_2 = 1$ if a randomly chosen person chose box $2$, its $0$ if they
>   chose a different box.
>
> $X_3 = 1$ if a randomly chosen person chose box a box different from
>   box $1$ and $2$, its $0$ if they chose box $1$ or $2$.
>
> Let $p_i \in (0,1)$ be the probability of a person choosing category
>   $i$. We ask a randomly chosen person for which box they would choose.
>   What is the distribution of $(X1, X2, X3)$? What are the parameters?

I guess we could just see it as $3$ boxes, since we group $3,...,k$ together. And we can see it
as some sort of Bernoulli distribution for three options instead of two, but I don't see which distribution that would be.

Any nudge in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: This is not clear.  Why isn't $X_1$, say, just determined by $p_1$?  That is, $X_1=1$ with probability $p_1$ and $X_1=0$ otherwise?  Same for $X_2$. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @lulu this is how the problem was formulated. I think they do mean that $X_1=1$ with probability $p_1$.

Comment: Ok, so then that's your answer.  $X_3$ you can get by subtracting or, alternatively, by summing $p_3+\cdots+p_k$.

Comment: It is just multinomial distribution, with $1$ trial only.